# Define a C# field in C++ class

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, managed

I would like to know if it is possible to declare a C# class member inside as C++ class as class field.

I have the `Guard` C# class and the `InvProvider` C++ class; inside the `InvProvider.h` file, I would like to write something like:

```
class InvProvider 
{
  public :
    InvProvider(void);
    InvProvider(const InvProvider &ref);
    virtual ~InvProvider();
    ...
    Guards::InvGuards::Guard^ g; // C# type field inside C++ class
};
```

But Intellisense suggests about `g`:

`Error: a member of a non-managed class cannot be a handle`.

I know that I can declare, instanziate and use a `Guard` instance inside a `InvProvider` function, but I need a member of this type inside my C++ class.

Comment: I think this link might help lead you in the right direction [Using Native C# in C++ with Help of C++/CLI](http://pragmateek.com/using-c-from-native-c-with-the-help-of-ccli-v2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but... is it possible to do that without using a C++/CLI wrapper?